# Getting data from nested json using python

Tags: python, sql, json, nested

I'm trying to get some data from a government website and store them in two different tables. One will contain the filenames and the release date (let's call this `filename`) and one will contain the actual data and the key to join with the `filename` (let's call this `datasplit`)

These data come into a JSON file I saved from the web page (I don't have an API for that). Here's a little example of how the JSON file looks:

```
{
    "filename": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "nome": "Societa' controllate di fatto dalla Presidenza del Consiglio dei Ministri e dai Ministeri",
            "aggiornamento": "04-02-2020",
            "datasplit": [
                {
                    "cf": "00081070591",
                    "den": "SIOG SOCIETA'ITALIANA OLEODOTTI DI GAETA SPA IN AMM.NE STRAORDINARIA",
                    "dm": "1513641600"
                },
                {
                    "cf": "00103540829",
                    "den": "INDUSTRIA SICILIANA ACIDO FOSFORICO S.P.A.IN LIQUIDAZIONE",
                    "dm": "1513641600"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "Enti o societa' controllate dalle Amministrazioni Centrali",
            "aggiornamento": "30-10-2019",
            "datasplit": [
                {
                    "cf": "00049100522",
                    "den": "MPS TENIMENTI POGGIO BONELLI E CHIGI SARACINI - SOC. AGRICOLA SPA",
                    "dm": "1513641600"
                },
                {
                    "cf": "00051010528",
                    "den": "SOCIETA' AGRICOLA SUVIGNANO S.R.L.",
                    "dm": "1513641600"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "nome": "Societa' quotate inserite nell'indice FTSE MIB della Borsa italiana",
            "aggiornamento": "19-12-2017",
            "datasplit": [
                {
                    "cf": "00079760328",
                    "den": "ASSICURAZIONI GENERALI S.P.A.",
                    "dm": "1513641600"
                },
                {
                    "cf": "00222620163",
                    "den": "FRENI BREMBO - SPA",
                    "dm": "1513641600"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So what I'd like to get is the `filename` table with `id, nome, aggiornamento` fields and the `datasplit` table with `id, aggiornamento, cf, den, dm`

What I've done so far is to get the JSON file (saving it locally) from the webpage and read it in my python program.

```
# this works
import json
sqlstatement = ''
with open('splitdata.json', 'r') as f: #this is where I saved the website content I want to Import
    jsondata = json.loads(f.read())
```

I was trying to build something that would go through the json file and build some `INSERT INTO table_name` SQL queries to later execute them and finally have my data in the database.

So, my problem is how to read the nested JSON first and how to insert the data in my database second (if you have a better solution than creating and running the SQL script).

When trying to cycle inside the JSON it seems that it only finds one element.

```
for json in jsondata:
    keylist = "("
    valuelist = "("
    firstPair = True
    for key, value in jsondata.items():
        if not firstPair:
            keylist += ", "
            valuelist += ", "
        firstPair = False
        keylist += key
        if type(value) in (str, unicode):
            valuelist += "'" + value + "'"
        else:
            valuelist += str(value)
    keylist += ")"
    valuelist += ")"

    sqlstatement += "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " " + keylist + " VALUES " + valuelist + "\n"

print(sqlstatement)
```

I know the code is incomplete to generate the correct SQL statements but i need help on how to get to the nested part of the JSON, the `datasplit` field. Could it be it's not treating it as a dictionary? If so, how can i eventually fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to solve the problem using Pandas which has SQL capabilities:

```py
import pandas as pd

for key, val in json_data.items():
    df = pd.json_normalize(val)
    df = df.explode('datasplit')
    df[['cf', 'den', 'dm']] = df.datasplit.apply(pd.Series)
    df = df.drop('datasplit', axis=1)

    df.to_sql(<name>, <con>)
```

This is what each datasplit (`df`) looks like:

```
   id                                               nome aggiornamento  \
0   2  Societa' controllate di fatto dalla Presidenza...    04-02-2020   
0   2  Societa' controllate di fatto dalla Presidenza...    04-02-2020   
1   1  Enti o societa' controllate dalle Amministrazi...    30-10-2019   
1   1  Enti o societa' controllate dalle Amministrazi...    30-10-2019   
2   4  Societa' quotate inserite nell'indice FTSE MIB...    19-12-2017   
2   4  Societa' quotate inserite nell'indice FTSE MIB...    19-12-2017   

            cf                                                den          dm  
0  00081070591  SIOG SOCIETA'ITALIANA OLEODOTTI DI GAETA SPA I...  1513641600  
0  00103540829  INDUSTRIA SICILIANA ACIDO FOSFORICO S.P.A.IN L...  1513641600  
1  00049100522  MPS TENIMENTI POGGIO BONELLI E CHIGI SARACINI ...  1513641600  
1  00051010528                 SOCIETA' AGRICOLA SUVIGNANO S.R.L.  1513641600  
2  00079760328                      ASSICURAZIONI GENERALI S.P.A.  1513641600  
2  00222620163                                 FRENI BREMBO - SPA  1513641600
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you are stuck at, but perhaps you aren't familiar with how dictionaries work?

```
jsondata['filename'] # has everything you want. you array of data.

# get the first element in the array
jsondata['filename'][0]
# result: {'id': 2, 'nome': "Societa' controllate di fatto dalla Presidenza del Consiglio dei Ministri e dai Ministeri", 'aggiornamento': '04-02-2020', 'datasplit': [{'cf': '00081070591', 'den': "SIOG SOCIETA'ITALIANA OLEODOTTI DI GAETA SPA IN AMM.NE STRAORDINARIA", 'dm': '1513641600'}, {'cf': '00103540829', 'den': 'INDUSTRIA SICILIANA ACIDO FOSFORICO S.P.A.IN LIQUIDAZIONE', 'dm': '1513641600'}]}

# second element 
jsondata['filename'][1]
# result: {'id': 1, 'nome': "Enti o societa' controllate dalle Amministrazioni Centrali", 'aggiornamento': '30-10-2019', 'datasplit': [{'cf': '00049100522', 'den': 'MPS TENIMENTI POGGIO BONELLI E CHIGI SARACINI - SOC. AGRICOLA SPA', 'dm': '1513641600'}, {'cf': '00051010528', 'den': "SOCIETA' AGRICOLA SUVIGNANO S.R.L.", 'dm': '1513641600'}]}

# access `datasplit` directly like 
jsondata['filename'][0]['datasplit']
# result: [{'cf': '00081070591', 'den': "SIOG SOCIETA'ITALIANA OLEODOTTI DI GAETA SPA IN AMM.NE STRAORDINARIA", 'dm': '1513641600'}, {'cf': '00103540829', 'den': 'INDUSTRIA SICILIANA ACIDO FOSFORICO S.P.A.IN LIQUIDAZIONE', 'dm': '1513641600'}]


# or in for loop
for data in jsondata['filename']:
    data['datasplit']
```